# UIProgressBar ignores code and gets stuck on random value after view returns from background

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I have a UIProgressBar inside of a UITableViewCell which updates every second in accordance to a countdown timer, which also runs inside of the cell's object. It works very well for the most part, until the app is backgrounded or another modal view goes over it – somehow, normal views don't trigger this.

Once the app returns from this state, the progress bar stops listening to the timer and gets stuck on the same random value (around 10%) that isn't referenced anywhere else in the app. The strange thing is, when I print the progress bar's current progress after modifying it in the timer, it returns correctly, despite the UI not respecting it.

Here's a recording of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/oZ9AGUh

And here's the relevant code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        (cell as! CountdownTable).timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            let nowToEvent = (cell as! CountdownTable).dateTarget - Date()
            let thenToEvent = (cell as! CountdownTable).dateTarget - (cell as! CountdownTable).dateWhenSet
            
            let elapsed = thenToEvent - nowToEvent
            (cell as! CountdownTable).countdownBar.setProgress(Float(elapsed / thenToEvent), animated: true)
            (cell as! CountdownTable).countdownDate.text = (cell as! CountdownTable).dateTarget.timeFromDate(from: Date())
        })
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as! CountdownTable).timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but the `layoutSubviews` is the wrong place to set up this timer. It can be called multiple times at points of time unrelated to appearance of this cell. You could easily end up with multiple timers and observers. I’d make sure to `timer?.invalidate()` right before you instantiate a new timer as a defensive programming measure. And the `timer` variable would be `weak`.

Comment: Hi @Rob, thanks for the tips. Can you recommend a better place to put the timer?

Comment: I bet this IS the cause of the problem. For reasons that aren't clear, dismissing the modal is causing your cell's layoutSubviews method to get called again. That's likely causing all sorts of mischief (creating a second timer, plus messing up your progress calculations.) I'd suggest doing your timer setup in your cell's awakeFromNib method (And also making your timer weak and invalidating it before setting it as Rob suggested.)

Comment: I might suggest the `UITableViewDelegate` starts it from [`tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview) and stops it from [`tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview). I'm still not sure that’s the problem (as the `countdownDate.text` appears to be correct and I don't see how duplicative timers could manifest the behavior you shared with us). I'd make sure there’s nothing that updates the `countdownBar` or `dateWhenSet` directly.

Comment: I wouldn't create a timer per cell. It is simpler to have a timer for your tableview and when it fires, you can iterate the currently visible cells and update them. That way you don't need to keep creating and invalidating timers. You should also run your timer at a faster rate than 1 second to get a smoother result; Timers can be quite jittery

Answer (score -1):

This code solves the problem of the progress bar not updating after the app is backgrounded or a modal view appears by using a single `Timer` for the entire table view, rather than a timer for each cell.

The key points of the solution are as follows:

1. The `Timer` instance is now part of the `UIViewController` managing the table view instead of being part of the individual `UITableViewCell`. This timer gets initiated when the view controller's view appears (`viewDidAppear(_:)`) and invalidated when the view disappears (`viewWillDisappear(_:)`).
2. The timer fires every 0.1 seconds and calls the `updateVisibleCells` function. The interval of 0.1 seconds is chosen to provide a smoother UI update. You can adjust this value based on your needs and performance considerations.
3. The `updateVisibleCells` function iterates over all currently visible cells in the table view (obtained by calling `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows`). It calculates the elapsed time and updates the progress of the progress bar for each visible cell.
4. This approach ensures the progress bar continues to update when the app returns from the background or when a modal view is dismissed, as the timer continues to run for the duration the view controller is visible, regardless of any changes at the cell level.
5. By not using a timer in each table cell, this approach also improves performance and battery efficiency, as only a single timer is used regardless of the number of visible cells. This can be especially beneficial when the table view has many cells.

Here's a refactored version of the code that takes into account the suggestions discussed by @Rob and @Paulw11. Note that this code assumes a model exists which stores the `dateWhenSet` and `dateTarget` values, as well as a method to calculate the `timeFromDate(from:)`.

```swift
class CountdownTable: UITableViewCell {
    var timer: Timer?
    var dateWhenSet: Date?
    var dateTarget: Date?
    var countdownBar: UIProgressView!
    var countdownDate: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // setup cell
    }
}

class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var timer: Timer?
    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateVisibleCells), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func updateVisibleCells() {
        guard let visibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else { return }
        for indexPath in visibleRows {
            guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CountdownTable else { continue }
            let nowToEvent = cell.dateTarget! - Date()
            let thenToEvent = cell.dateTarget! - cell.dateWhenSet!
            let elapsed = thenToEvent - nowToEvent
            cell.countdownBar.setProgress(Float(elapsed / thenToEvent), animated: true)
            cell.countdownDate.text = cell.dateTarget?.timeFromDate(from: Date())
        }
    }

}
```

This code sets up a single timer in `viewDidAppear(_:)` that fires every 0.1 seconds to update the progress bars for currently visible cells. The timer is invalidated in `viewWillDisappear(_:)` to ensure that it stops when the view controller is no longer visible. This is a more efficient approach than creating and managing separate timers for each cell.

This solution assumes that the `UITableViewCell` subclass has properties `countdownBar`, `countdownDate`, `dateTarget` and `dateWhenSet`. Make sure these properties exist and are properly configured.

This solution maintains the updating of the progress bar and the countdown timer in all circumstances outlined in the original problem. By moving the timer to the view controller and iterating over only the visible cells, it also provides a more efficient and smooth update of the UI.